# <Header> tag HTML5 inside div

Tags: html, seo

just wondering, is it bad practice to place a `<header>` tag inside a div tag when designing a site that mostly uses `html5` elements and the doctype is for html5? Thanks!

Also, should I place the `Nav` outside the header or inside, or does it really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not strictly, but there are some contextual semantics that are implied by embedding the `header` under elements other than the body. Depending on how you structure the document, you may run into unexpected behaviours. See below.

HTML5, as far as I can tell, is a DTD-less document type. Which does not apply strict rules as it pertains to document structure validation. According to the W3C document on `HTML5` the:

> *... header element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A header typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids.* [[1]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element)

Basically, what this seems to indicate is that, if the `header` element is directly under the `body` of the document, it applies to the page as a whole, but if contained under another element which identifies a section the `header` applies more specifically to the nearest ancestor.

Bear in mind though that a `<div>` is not a sectioning element as pointed out by [Tomasz Zielinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176186/tomasz-zielinski). Originally I had thought it was. If you want your header to apply only to a specific section of the page, it is best to use one of the defined sectioning elements to encompass the header, as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html

E.g.

```
<div>
  <section>
    <header>...</header>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sean also, is it bad practice to place a `<nav>` inside a header or should I place it just underneath? I should be placing these links on the left hand side of the html page, so what do you think?

Comment: Placing the `<nav>` inside the header seems to be natural and acceptable practice by the W3C, take a look at the last example here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/header

Comment: -1, div is neither a sectioning content nor a sectioning root.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that it is a bad practice. However, still make sure you have it placed int the general area where it should be.

Here is a [link](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_header_tag.cfm) that might help you understand the location of your header.

Answer (score 2):

No, as long as you respect the content semantics and that your header contains header information. You can wrap it in a div with no SEO drawbacks.